# Add a relative reference column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am attempting to add a relative reference number based on two values.

The dataset includes a client (column B) and batch (column C).
Each client can have multiple batches which can start at any number (minimum being 0) and increases sequentially the more batches there are for the client.
This means a client can have batches 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. but they could also have batches 2, 3, 4, 5, etc.

I am trying to create a relative reference for the client-batches (see column E in the screenshot).

Desired Output
[image]

This would have to be done per client.

I managed to create a macro which selects a specific client ID. I have not figured out how to cycle through them or add the values into column E:

```vb
Sub select_relative_column()

    Dim ref As Range
    Dim ref2 As Range

    For i = 1 To 100
        If Cells(i, 2) = 10000201 Then
            Set ref = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5))
            If ref2 Is Nothing Then
                Set ref2 = ref
            Else
                Set ref2 = Union(ref2, ref)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    ref2.Select
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty understanding how your expected result is derived. For example, why is 6 your 'relative' value in line 13 of your screenshot? Why are you setting range values in your code and why do you `Select` `ref2` at the end of your code? I don't see anywhere in your code where you're outputting a reference number.

Comment: Hi Michael, the 6 shows that it is the 6th batch. The 1st batch was the batch with the value 0 (see column C). In the code which I made I have only managed to select the subset which is based on the client value. I suppose I would not have to Select ref2 if I can directly do something to the selection. As for the outputting. I have not gotten that far I am still stuck at the selection logic.

Comment: That still doesn't fully explain how you derive your reference number. If batch #5 gets a reference of 6 then why does batch #2 get a reference of both 3 and 1 (row 7 & 14)?

Comment: The reference is per client so in row 7 this is the 3rd batch for client 10000201. In row 14 this is the 1st batch for client 20000202.

Comment: Row 13 is the first batch in the list for client 20000201 so why does it get a relative value of 6?

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. You are right. It should be "1", I have adjusted the screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you don't need a macro, you can do it with a formula in Excel.

if client is in column C and batch is in column D, with data from rows 5 to 24, here is the formula for row 5 (can be copied down)

```
    =$D5-MIN(UNIQUE(FILTER($D$5:$D$24,$C$5:$C$24=$C5,)))+1
```

Comment: Thanks HannahW this works exactly how I need it to. I think I was making the problem too complex for myself.

Answer (score 2):

### Add Relative Reference

```vb
Sub PopulateRelative()
    
    Const SHEET_NAME As String = "Sheet1"
    Const CLIENT_COLUMN As Long = 2
    Const BATCH_COLUMN As Long = 3
    Const RELATIVE_COLUMN As Long = 5
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets(SHEET_NAME)
    
    Dim rg As Range, rCount As Long
    
    With ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rCount = .Rows.Count - 1 ' exclude headers
        Set rg = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1)
    End With
    
    Dim cData: cData = rg.Columns(CLIENT_COLUMN)
    Dim bData: bData = rg.Columns(BATCH_COLUMN)
    
    Dim rData: ReDim rData(1 To rCount, 1 To 1)
    
    Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    Dim r As Long, Client As Long, Batch As Long
    
    For r = 1 To rCount
        Client = cData(r, 1)
        If Not dict.Exists(Client) Then
            Set dict(Client) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        End If
        Batch = bData(r, 1)
        If Not dict(Client).Exists(Batch) Then
            dict(Client)(Batch) = dict(Client).Count + 1
        End If
        rData(r, 1) = dict(Client)(Batch)
    Next r
    
    rg.Columns(RELATIVE_COLUMN).Value = rData

    MsgBox "Relative column populated.", vbInformation

End Sub
```